# Exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Not Found' in (...) REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-api-php-client

I am working with the Google Tag Manager API to retrieve accounts and containers with a Service Account and my project is hosted on Google App Engine.

This works for retrieving ALL accounts that user has access to, like this:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setApplicationName("gtmdocx");


    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers']);

    $service = new Google_Service_TagManager($client);
    $results = $service->accounts->listAccounts();


    $jsonp = json_encode($results);
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($jsonp).')';
```

This gives me results.

But, when it comes to listing containers I get this error:

> Type: Google_Service_Exception Code: 404 Message: Not Found File:
>   /base/data/home/apps/h~gtmdocx/20170908t154630.403962727349911910/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php Line: 118

There is so little documentation on PHP part of Google Tag Manager API, I've tried searching with no luck.

This is my "List containers" code, everything is just like the first code with retrieving Accounts that is working but this is the code for Containers:

```
 $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.publish'
        ]);

        $service = new Google_Service_TagManager($client);
        $containers = $service->accounts_containers->listAccountsContainers('1746756959');
```

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: I recently received this error, we had updated settings on our server and noticed that php_mbstring.dll was not enabled anymore which broke a few things. I enabled it and some of the other pages work, except for this google error. for me though, in the error log just above this is the line `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll' ... No such file or directory in Unknown...` which doesnt entirely make sense, maybe it will help though?

Comment: I receive the same error with a service account and Google Calendar Api (php): never received a more useless error message